# How to check of object exists in Google Cloud Storage using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-storage

Does anyone know how to check if an object exists inside a Google Cloud Storage bucket via C#?

Answer (score 3):

To test for the existence of an object without generating an exception when it isn't found, use the ListObjects() method.

The documentation on the *prefix* argument is a little misleading.

> Only objects with names that start with this string will be returned.

In fact, the full object name can be used and will result in positive matches.

```
using( var client = StorageClient.Create() )
{
    var results = client.ListObjects( "bucketname", "test.jpg" );
    var exists = results?.Count() > 0;
    return exists;
}
```

I believe protecting results w/ the nullable test is unnecessary. Even when I get no results with this code results is still not null. That said, I feel safer with that added protection since we are explicitly trying to avoid a try/catch.

Obviously this code could be shortened, but I wanted to demonstrate each step of the process for clarity.

This code was tested in a .net6 Console App using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 version 3.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 [library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/index.html)

```
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;

public class StorageClass 
{
    public bool IsObjectExist(string bucketName, string objectname)
    {
        var client = StorageClient.Create();
        return client.GetObject(bucketName, objectname) != null ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works when the file does exist.   But when it does not it throws an exception.  

Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
No such object: {bucket}/{folder}/file-that-doesn't-exist.pdf [404]
Errors [
 Message[No such object:  {bucket}/{folder}/file-that-doesn't-exist.pdf] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]

There has to be a better way to handle this than using a try catch?

Thanks for your help!